# How to use casper.page.close() to avoid memory leak for multiple page open

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

When I open many pages in an array (in thousands), there seems to be memory leak because I monitor the process memory in Windows.

I read this and decided to use http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/close.html

Below is the code

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
      verbose: true,
      logLevel: 'debug',
      pageSettings: {
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0'
      }
    }),
    utils = require('utils');

casper.start();

casper.thenOpen('http://www.google.com/', function(response) {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.then(function() {
  casper.page.close();
});

casper.thenOpen('http://www.yahoo.com/', function(response) {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run(function() {
  console.log('End');
  casper.exit();
});
```

However it gave me error:

```
Error: cannot access member `customHeaders' of deleted QObject
  test:1182 in open
  test:1555 in _step
  test:1335 in runStep
  test:332 in checkStep
```

So how do I close the `page` object each time before open up another page? Or the bigger question is how to prevent memory leak in Phantom.js?

Comment: Do you have update? How you resolved a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what is happening in this scenario but here is a solution to your problem:

```
...
casper.then(function() {
    casper.page.close();
    casper.page = require('webpage').create();
});

casper.thenOpen('http://www.yahoo.com/', function(response) {
    this.wait(1000, function() {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
    });
});
...
```

close() - "Close the page and releases the memory heap associated with it. Do not use the page instance after calling this." <- This is from the phantomjs documentation. You need to create a new page instance if you want to continue opening sites. Hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't work as the yahoo page is blank when I do capture(). The google page is fine though.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't wait long enough. Mine is blank if I don't wait a second but it could take longer. [debug] [phantom] opening url: http://www.yahoo.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 5/5: done in 726ms.
[info] [phantom] Step 6/6: done in 822ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 1000ms.
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
Yahoo! Canada
[info] [phantom] Done 6 steps in 1870ms

Comment: That could be the case but isn't there a way to avoid guess work on the wait number?

Comment: @HP. You can use any of the `waitFor...()` methods, waiting for resources, selectors... or create your own wait logic with `waitFor()`